# In an electrical charged suit and at rest in an $\vec E$ field can you describe your situation as being at rest in a gravitational field?

Tags: gravity

Suppose you are put in a uniformly electrical charged suit so that you're surrounded by a thin layer of electrons (the suit is negatively charged). You're put on a big plateau at rest in a uniform $\vec E$ field which pulls the electrons (staying put in the suit) down. We adjust the $\vec E$ field (or the number of electrons in the suit) so you are pulled down on the plateau in such a way that you feel the same force as your mass would experience at rest in a gravity field (which is, in fact, an electric force).

My question: Can you describe your situation by stating that you're standing at rest in a (locally uniform) gravity field?

Comment: There would be no gravitational pull in internal organs. Blood veins etc. would have to adjust, just as they must for astronauts in space. Furthermore your arms would not want to hang down along your side and your legs would not want to be closed, because the suit repels itself. Unless the charge may redistribute, in which case a gravitational pull will disappear from such parts. I can't say how much you would understand of your situation, but I guess it will feel weird.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: That Steeven is right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be no gravitational pull in internal organs. Blood veins etc. would have to adjust, just as they must for astronauts in space. Furthermore your arms would not want to hang down along your side and your legs would not want to be closed, because the suit repels itself. Unless the charge may redistribute, in which case a gravitational pull will disappear from such parts. I can't say how much you would understand of your situation, but I guess it will feel weird. – Steeven